# Can I relay my USB modem connection to my wireless router?

Tags: networking, usb, router, wireless-networking, modem

I got a wireless modem that needs to plug into my computer in order for it to work.

Is it possible to hook up this computer to my wireless router so that other devices can connect using the same connection? (Effectively using my computer as a modem?)

If I try to share internet connection on LAN, my wireless router doesn't seem to pick up any connection details. I plugged RJ45 cable from my computer into the wireless routers WAN point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "no" - unfortunately. It's not possible to bridge the dk 3 usb modem.

Answer (score 1):

Plug your computer into the wireless router (in the WAN-port if you have one) using a regular UTP patch cable. Go to network connections and right click your LAN connection. Click properties and go to the tab called "Sharing". This window pops up:

[image: Window]

Make sure the top checkbox is checked, the bottom one is optional but I prefer and recommend leaving it unchecked. Connect to the internet using your USB modem, other network devices should now be able to connect through your computer.

Comment: Is this through my computer (ie ad-hoc wireless) or can I plug a cable from my computer to my wireless router?

Comment: Plug a cable in your computer through the LAN connection and plug the other end of the cable in (the WAN-port of) the router.

Comment: yes. I tried. I shared my LAN connection but my Wireless router isn't picking up any details from my computer (ip/dns/gateway) - im sure im missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

I successfully did something like this awhile back when I needed to share a wireless signal to other computers on the LAN network.

- The RJ45 cable should go from your computer (which has the USB modem) to a LAN port on the wireless router.
- On Windows XP, please bridge the connection between the USB Modem and the Local Area Connection.
- On the router's webpage, disable the router to act as a DHCP server (it should be provided now by the computer)

If all is successful, when you go to a different computer and check the IP configuration, you should get a unique IP address with a gateway of the IP address of your first computer (with the USB modem).

Play around with some of the settings on the wireless router to get the configuration that works for you.  Each router is unfortunately a little different.

Comment: Computer says "To create a Network Bridge , you must select atleast two high speed internet connections  that are not being used by internet connection sharing."

Comment: You'll need to take the internet connection sharing off of the computer.  The bridge will, in effect, do the same thing.